# Como desmarcar un RadioButton en android? (solamente es uno, sin radio group)

Tags: java, android, radiobutton

Como desmarcar un RadioButtom en android? resulta que le de doy clic y se marca pero no lo puedo desmarcar, probe poniendo un click listener pero no me funciono

```
 rdbBiopsiaCon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rdbBiopsiaCon.isChecked()){
                rdbBiopsiaCon.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                 rdbBiopsiaCon.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hola podrias mejor usar un CheckBox :D para ello, tambien podrias subir tu xml :D

Comment: Como desmarcar un `RadioButton`??. Pues haciendo que pertenezca a un `RadioGroup`, en el cual hayan 2 o más radiobutton. Si sólo quieres utilizar nada más que una opción, para ello mejor un `Checkbox` como te han indicado. También podrías usar un botón para desmarcar el `RadioButton`

Comment: Te pongo un enlace a la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton#java)